# Android Exception when resuming the app after a couple of hours

Tags: android, exception, onresume

I get this weird exception when I resume my app after a few hours. The exception looks like this:

> 01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401): Process: com.app, PID: 10401
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app/com.app.HomeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already added!
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already added!
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1828)
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:213)
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401):    at com.app.SlidingSherlockFragmentActivity.onCreate(SlidingSherlockFragmentActivity.java:24)
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401):    at com.app.BaseSlidingMenuActivity.onCreate(BaseSlidingMenuActivity.java:17)
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401):    at com.app.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:81)
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401):    ... 11 more
>   01-08 08:38:39.421: W/ActivityManager(768):   Force finishing activity com.app/.HomeActivity
>   01-08 08:38:39.941: W/ActivityManager(768): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{43577368 u0 com.app/.HomeActivity t549 f}
>   01-08 08:38:40.051: W/Sidekick_LocationOracleImpl(15233): Best location was null
>   01-08 08:38:49.371: E/WindowManager(768): Starting window AppWindowToken{45524120 token=Token{433ba630 ActivityRecord{43577368 u0 com.app/.HomeActivity t549}}} timed out
>   01-08 08:38:50.041: W/ActivityManager(768): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{43577368 u0 com.app/.HomeActivity t549 f}

Line 81 of HomeActivity is the following line in the onCreate method.

> super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

My Activities don't have any launchMode in the  `AndroidManifest.xml`

I dont really know what to do and I can't find anything about this exception.

Comment: did you have any global value? save your values in `onSaveInstanceState` and restore that in `onCreate()`

Comment: Getting the same error. @w.donk: how you resolved this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add a fragment to your activity that has already been added. The following line near the middle part of the stack trace you pasted seems to indicate so:

> E/AndroidRuntime(10401): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already added! 01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1828) 01-08 08:38:39.421: E/AndroidRuntime(10401): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:213)